# Android - use res/values and res/values-<qualifiers> simultaneously for different resource types

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I would like to load dimens.xml based upon the screen size, but use the same colors regardless of screen size.

I have the following directory structure

```
res
 res/values
  colors.xml
 res/values-small
  dimens.xml
 res/values-normal
  dimens.xml
 res/values-large
  dimens.xml
 res/values-xlarge
  dimens.xml
```

I am new to Android but it seems that the system picks only a single **values** directory at load time. What this means is that, although I get the dimens.xml from the values-*qualifier* directory as desired, I have no colors defined.

Is there some way to define certain kinds of *values* resources that are used for any device configuration, while defining other kinds of *values* resources on a per-configuration basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That directory structure should work as it is. From the documentation for [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

> Whereas XML resource files in other res/ subdirectories define a
>   single resource based on the XML filename, files in the values/
>   directory describe multiple resources. For a file in this directory,
>   each child of the resources element defines a single resource. For
>   example, a  element creates an R.string resource and a color
>   element creates an R.color resource.

That means that unless you have a particular color in (say) the `values-large` directory, the value from `values` will be used for it. The granularity is **per-resource**, and the names of the actual files are unimportant.

Comment: awesome. I was getting some errors in the preview panel that I misinterpreted. It is now working as I expected.